# Javascript Add-in for Word 64 Bit Issues

Tags: office-js

We are planning to move away from Activex (32 bit) and VBA which works fine in 32 bit but not in 64 bit using JavaScript API. Are there any issues all of you have noticed which we should be aware of before starting the project specially JavaScript API and 64 bit.

Thanks in advance
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

The repo at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js is where non-Microsoft developers report bugs in the Office.js APIs. I just searched the issues for "64". It looks like the only hits are people specifying their OS version, but no cases where the reported problem correlated with 64-bit OS.

For what it's worth, in 3 years working on the Office Add-in Developer Education team, I don't recall ever hearing of an issue that correlated with 64-bit OS.

Comment: I am going thru the list of issues. Are  there any big red flags you have encountered while using JavaScript API to word compare to VBA or Activex.

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: @Manoj Nothing I would call a red flag. There are things you can do with VBA that cannot yet be done with Office.js. But there are things you can do with JavaScript add-ins that you can't do with VBA. Mainly, your add-ins cross platform, not just Windows.

Comment: Where can I find list of things which I can do with VBA but not JavaScript. We are developing add-in which will replace our current VBA and activeX add-in as they don't work in 64bit office.